# set up wildcard subdomain on Ubuntu 18.08 (Laravel/Homestead)

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, homestead, wildcard-subdomain

I'm trying to set up wildcard subdomains for a Laravel project in a Laravel/Homestead enviorement, but cannot figure it out why this does not works.

The [local](http://jslim.net/blog/2015/12/01/setup-wildcard-subdomain-in-laravel-homestead/) setup was successfull, but cannot make it work on the Ubuntu. I've set up in the nginx conf file the server name:

```
server_name example.test *.example.test
```

Restarted the nginx, but after accessing any subdomain, there is no activity in access_log.

how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the best/easiest way to solve this is the [vagrant-rubydns](https://github.com/fivetanley/vagrant-rubydns) plugin:

I hope this will help somebody else.